# excel export from jira webwork plugin

Tags: excel, report, jira, webwork

I write my own webwork plugin for Jira 3.12, which make a report for version progress of some projects. I can't use standart jira report plugin, because customer want two-step parameters choise (some projects and set of versions for every selected project). He also need excel export of this report. But I don't understand, how to transfer this parameters to ConfigureReport or don't know another way do this.

How can I add excel export to my webwork plugin?

Comment: Hi Stanislav! Instead of writing the answer into question with an edit, its better to answer it yourself and mark it as an answer. This way, it's easier for future reader to benefit from it - and it'll be marked as an answered question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. I bind javascript on HTML button in velocity temlate:

```
function generateexcel(tableid)
        {
            var table= document.getElementById(tableid);
            table.border = 1;
            var html = table.outerHTML;
            window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
        }
```

Where tableid is ID of report table in this template.

Answer (score 0):

To get some samples on using webwork you may have a look at https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.consultingtoolsmiths.jira.samples.webwork